# ReactJS Parent component state is getting overridden by Child component state

Tags: reactjs

I have started learning reactjs last week. I am creating a react app that manages book quotes by book titles and authors. I have designed the react components on books page like this,

[image]

Books component is parent of NewBook and BookList components. I am using `state` in Books and NewBook. One for array of books and another for adding new book. I want to update state from Books (parent) in NewBook (child) by calling a addBook (function) from parent passed as a prop to the child. But I am having an issue where parent's state in it's addBook function is getting overridden.

**Books.js**

```
import React from "react";

import { BookList } from "./BookList";
import { NewBook } from "./NewBook";


export class Books extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            books: [
                {title: "The Black Swan", author: "Nassim Nicholas Taleb"},
                {title: "The Lean Startup", author: "Eric Ries"}
            ]
        };
    }

    addBook(title, author) {
        console.log("adding..");
        const newBooks = this.state.books;
        newBooks.push({title: title, author: author});
        this.setState({
            books: newBooks
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 offset-3"> 
                <NewBook onAdd={this.addBook} defaultTitle={''} defaultAuthor={''} />

                <BookList books={this.state.books}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**NewBook.js**

```
import React from "react";

export class NewBook extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            title: props.defaultTitle,
            author: props.defaultAuthor
        };
    }

    add() {
        this.props.onAdd(this.state.title, this.state.author);
        this.setState({title: this.props.defaultTitle, author: this.props.defaultAuthor});
    }

    updateTitle(event) {
        this.setState({title: event.target.value});
    }

    updateAuthor(event) {
        this.setState({author: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <textarea 
                        className="form-control col-md-12" 
                        rows="2" placeholder="I am reading this book named" 
                        value={this.state.title}
                        onChange={(event) => this.updateTitle(event)} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="author" className="font-italic font-weight-light">by</label>
                    <input className="form-control form-control-sm col-md-12" 
                        id="author" placeholder="this author" 
                        value={this.state.author}
                        onChange={(event) => this.updateAuthor(event)}/> 
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <button disabled={this.state.title === '' || this.state.author === ''} onClick={() => this.add()} className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    } }
```

**BookList.js (no issue in this component)**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export class BookList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var books = this.props.books;
        return (
            <ul>
                {books.map((item, i) => <li key={i}><Link to={{ pathname: "/quotes", search: "?title=" + item.title }}>{item.title}</Link> by <Link to={{ pathname: "/quotes", search: "?author=" + item.author }}>{item.author}</Link></li>)}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

**When I click Add, I get an error**

```
adding..
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'books' of undefined
    at Object.addBook [as onAdd] (Books.js:44)
    at NewBook.add (NewBook.js:40)
    at onClick (NewBook.js:93)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:104)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:142)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:191)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:205)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:470)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:492)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:590)
```

Have this newbie missed something? By the way I am using

```
"react": "^16.3.1",
"react-dom": "^16.3.1",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `addBook` to the class in the constructor, otherwise `this` in `addBook` will be referencing the function itself instead of the class:

```
this.addBook = this.addBook.bind(this);
```

Alternatively, change it to arrow function which doesn't bind `this` to the function.

```
addBook = (title, author) => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Used the arrow function and it's fixed. Cheers. I must have missed that part from the lectures. Can you throw in some links?

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56. Also see https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your event-handling methods in the constructor, otherwise 'this' will not refer to anything.

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html